# on_touch_widget kivy all other widgets gets activated

Tags: python, kivy

on implementing below code every time last widget gets activated
and after that each and every widget gets activated
please solve this

on implementing below code every time last widget gets activated
and after that each and every widget gets activated
please solve this
on implementing below code every time last widget gets activated
and after that each and every widget gets activated
please solve this

on implementing below code every time last widget gets activated
and after that each and every widget gets activated
please solve this

on implementing below code every time last widget gets activated
and after that each and every widget gets activated
please solve this
`

```
from pieces import matrix
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color,Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
class Sprite(Image):
    def __init__(self,size=None,**kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if size==None:
            self.size = self.texture_size
        else:self.size=size
class Basket(Widget):
    def __init__(self,source,pos,name,**kwargs):
        super(Basket,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.speed=4
        self.name=name
        self.image=Sprite(source=source,pos=pos,size=[100,100])
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.size=self.image.size
        print self.size
    def update_y(self,a):
        final=a*100+50
        if self.image.center_y==final:return True
        elif self.image.center_y<final:self.image.center_y+=self.speed
        else:self.image.center_y-=self.speed
        return False
    def update_x(self,a):
        final=a*100+50
        if self.image.center_x==final:return True
        elif self.image.center_x<final:self.image.center_x+=self.speed
        else:self.image.center_x-=self.speed
        return False
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            print self.name
class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Game,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.matrix=matrix()
        self.add_widget(Sprite(source='images/gray.jpg'))
        for i in range(2):
            self.ids[str(i)]=Basket(source='images/basket.jpg',name=str(i),pos=(i*100,i*100))
            self.add_widget(self.ids[str(i)])
            print i
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/60.0)
        # self.matrix.shuffle()
    def update(self,ab):
        if self.matrix.up:
            if reduce(lambda a,i:self.ids[str(i)].update_y(self.matrix.y[i]) and a ,range(4),True):
                self.matrix.shuffle()
        else:
            if reduce(lambda a,i:self.ids[str(i)].update_x(self.matrix.x[i]) and a,range(4),True):
                self.matrix.shuffle()
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        print touch.grab(self)
class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        g=Game(size=(400,400))
        Window.size=g.size
        return g
GameApp().run()
```

`

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish and refine your question to remove the duplicate text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy doesn't perform touch collision by default, so that widgets can interact with touches that do not collide with them (since the widget arrangement is not necessarily the same as the gui touch arrangement).

You can just perform the collision check yourself:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        do_stuff()
```